# Paper-menu-button closes when scroll-bar is clicked and released

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer

I have a polymer paper-menu-button in my html webpage, when the user clicks the button the many selections and the overflow appear with the overflow handled by the scroll bar.

However, for some reason when the user tries to view the overflow via mouse button 1 and the scroll bar, when they release the mouse button 1 the paper-menu-button closes and you cannot see any selections anymore.

Is there a way to exclude clicks on the scroll-bar from closing the selection screen of the button?

I have tried these solutions

```
body /deep/ core-menu {
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

body /deep/ core-menu {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Solution 1 does not change any behavior and solution 2 creates overflow to be displayed on button-press instead of on scroll.

Comment: I think you should create a bug report. This is something the component should handle by itself.

Comment: Yea, please file a bug at https://github.com/polymer/paper-menu-button/issues for this.

Comment: I have posted the bug, yet I have not received any updates.